# Fast replacing values in dataframe in R

Tags: r, replace, dataframe

I have a dataframe of 150,000 rows with 2,000 columns containing values, some being negatives. 
I am replacing those negative values by 0, but it is extremely slow to do so (~60min or more).

`df[df   < 0] = 0`

where `df[,1441:1453]` looks like (all columns/values numeric):

```
  V1441 V1442 V1443 V1444 V1445 V1446 V1447 V1448 V1449 V1450 V1451 V1452 V1453
1     3     1     0     4     4    -2     0     3    12     5    17    34    27
2     0     1     0     7     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
3     0     2     0     1     2     3     6     1     2     1    -6     3     1
4     1     2     3     6     1     2     1    -6     3     1    -4     1     0
5     1     2     1    -6     3     1    -4     1     0     0     1     0     0
6     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     2     2
```

Is there a way to speed up such process, eg the way I am doing it is utterly slow, and there is faster approach for this ? 
Thanks.

Comment: 150,000 rows x 2000 columns : this is correct

Comment: Can you please [show us](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) how your data looks like? Are all columns numeric?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try transforming your df to a matrix.

```
df <- data.frame(a=rnorm(1000),b=rnorm(1000))
m <- as.matrix(df)
m[m<0] <- 0
df <- as.data.frame(m)
```

Comment: Really really faster!

Answer (score 23):

Both your original approach and the current answer create an object the same size as `m` (or `df`) when creating `m<0` (the matrix approach is quicker because there is less internal copying with `[<-` compared with `[<-.data.frame`

You can use `lapply` and `replace`, then you are only looking at a vector or `length (nrow(df))` each time
and not copying so much

```
df <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(x){replace(x, x <0,0)})
```

The above code should be quite effiicent.

If you use `data.table`, then most of the memory (and) time inefficiency of the `data.frame` approach is removed. It would be ideal for a large data situation like yours.

```
library(data.table)
# this really shouldn't be 
DT <- lapply(df, function(x){replace(x, x <0,0)})
# change to data.table
setattr(DT, 'class', c('data.table','data.frame'))
# or 
# DT <- as.data.table(df, function(x){replace(x, x <0,0)})
```

You could set keys  on all the columns and then replacing by reference for key values less than 0

Answer (score 0):

Another data.table answer, might be faster, and definitely should consume less memory.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(108)
d = data.table(a=rnorm(1000),b=rnorm(1000))
set.colwise = function(x, i, j, value) {
  replace_dot_j = function(e, j) {
    if (is.symbol(e) && identical(e, as.symbol(".j"))) return(j)
    if (is.call(e)) {
      if (e[[1L]] == ".j") e[[1L]] = j
      for (i in seq_along(e)[-1L]) if (!is.null(e[[i]])) e[[i]] = replace_dot_j(e[[i]], j)
    }
    e
  }
  for (jj in j) eval(substitute(
    set(x, .i, .j, value),
    list(
      .i=replace_dot_j(substitute(i), jj),
      .j=jj
    )
  ))
  invisible(x)
}
d
set.colwise(d, i = which(d[[.j]] < 0), j = c("a","b"), value = 0)
d
```

`.j` symbol used in `i` argument is iterated and replaced with columns from `j` argument.