# Replace values in one data frame from values in another data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I need to change individual identifiers that are currently alphabetical to numerical. I have created a data frame where each alphabetical identifier is associated with a number

```
individuals num.individuals (g4)
1           ZYO              64
2           KAO              24
3           MKU              32
4           SAG              42
```

What I need to replace ZYO with the number 64 in my main data frame (g3) and like wise for all the other codes.

My main data frame (g3) looks like this

```
  SAG YOG GOG BES ATR ALI COC CEL DUN EVA END GAR HAR HUX ISH INO JUL
1                   2                                                
2                   2                 EVA                            
3 SAG               2                 EVA                            
4                   2                                                
5 SAG               2                                                
6                   2
```

Now on a small scale I can write a code to change it like I did with ATR

```
g3$ATR <- as.character(g3$ATR)
g3[g3$target == "ATR" | g3$ATR == "ATR","ATR"] <- 2
```

But this is time consuming and increased chance of human error.

I know there are ways to do this on a broad scale with NAs

I think maybe we could do a for loop for this, but I am not good enough to write one myself.

I have also been trying to use this function which I feel like may work but I am not sure how to logically build this argument, it was posted on the questions board here
[Fast replacing values in dataframe in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835942/fast-replacing-values-in-dataframe-in-r)

```
df <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(x){replace(x, x <0,0)})
```

I have tried to work my data into this by

```
df <- as.data.frame(lapply(g4, function(g3){replace(x, x <0,0)})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach using the `data.table` package:

First, create a reproducible example similar to your data:

```
require(data.table)
ref <- data.table(individuals=1:4,num.individuals=c("ZYO","KAO","MKU","SAG"),g4=c(64,24,32,42))
g3 <- data.table(SAG=c("","SAG","","SAG"),KAO=c("KAO","KAO","",""))
```

Here is the `ref` table:

```
   individuals num.individuals g4
1:           1             ZYO 64
2:           2             KAO 24
3:           3             MKU 32
4:           4             SAG 42
```

And here is your `g3` table:

```
   SAG KAO
1:     KAO
2: SAG KAO
3:        
4: SAG
```

And now we do our find and replacing:

```
g3[ , lapply(.SD,function(x) ref$g4[chmatch(x,ref$num.individuals)])]
```

And the final result:

```
   SAG KAO
1:  NA  24
2:  42  24
3:  NA  NA
4:  42  NA
```

And if you need more speed, the `fastmatch` package might help with their `fmatch` function:

```
require(fastmatch)
g3[ , lapply(.SD,function(x) ref$g4[fmatch(x,ref$num.individuals)])]

   SAG KAO
1:  NA  24
2:  42  24
3:  NA  NA
4:  42  NA
```