# Replacing values in DataFrame to NA in Julia

Tags: dataframe, julia

What is the most elegant way to replace a value(say 99) to NA in a DataFrame in Julia?

I am considering using an iterator to skim each row and check each value for 99, etc. I would like to know if there is a better way to do this.

```
using Taro
Taro.init()
tempdf =Taro.readxl("/path/to/xls/", "Sheet1", "A1:CW24983"; header=false)
#Need one line command to replace all the 99s in the 24983 X 101 DataFrame to NA
```

Here is the MWE :

```
Pkg.add("RDatasets")
using RDatasets, DataFrames
datafr = dataset("datasets","anscombe")
#Replace each instance of 10(for e.g : (1,X1), (1,X2)) with NA
```

Edit 1 : Question for Julia similar to one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835942/fast-replacing-values-in-dataframe-in-r) for R.

Comment: You can go over each column this way: `[d[d[nm] .== 99, nm] = NA for nm in names(d)]`, though there may be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [jverzani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/340844/jverzani)

[d[d[nm] .== 99, nm] = NA for nm in names(d)]

Comment: It's good that your problem is solved, but taking a suggestion from a comment to your question and posting it as a self answer is not very fair. Why not invite jverzani to post an answer instead?

Comment: The other way: filling all NA of a DataFrame to 0: `[t[isna(t[nm]), nm] = 0 for nm in names(t)]`

Comment: NA apparently no longer has any meaning in Julia 1.x, and trying to assign to NaN generates an error.

Answer (score 0):

How about this: `tempdf = DataFrame(replace!(convert(Matrix, tempdf), 99=>"NA"))` ?