prettyNum function in a dataframe with numerical and character columns
I have this sample dataframe
df <- data.frame(status=c('single', 'married', 'married', "fff"),
                 education=c(3456, 898989899, 23939004, NA),
                 income=c('34.5%', '88.456%', '92', NA))
df

I execute the following code to replace the decimal points with a comma in the character columns only
df1<-df %>% mutate(across(where(is.character), ~ str_replace_all(., "\\.", ",")))

The output df1 is OK.
Next, I want to put dot ONLY to the values of the numerical columns. For example I want to have 3.456,  898.989.899, etc
But I have difficulty doing this. I tried
df2<- df1   %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric) ,    ~   prettyNum(., big.mark=".")         ))

but although it seems to work, I get a warning message.
Warning message:
There were 5 warnings in `mutate()`.
The first warning was:
ℹ In argument: `across(where(is.numeric), ~prettyNum(., big.mark = "."))`.
Caused by warning in `prettyNum()`:
! 'big.mark' and 'decimal.mark' are both '.', which could be confusing
ℹ Run `dplyr::last_dplyr_warnings()` to see the 4 remaining warnings.

Also, in df2, I no longer have numeric columns, as indicated by str(df2). All
columns are character columns which is something that I do not want, because NA becomes "NA", so in the excel instead  of having blank cells, I will be having "NA" strings. I want to maintain the numerical class of the corresponding columns.
Is there a way to avoid these complications?
Note that my real dataset contains hundrends of such numeric and character columns and thousands of rows, so a more general code would help.

Ensure you indicate what the decimal mark should be:
df1 %>% 
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~prettyNum(., big.mark=".",decimal.mark = ',')))

   status   education  income
1  single       3.456   34,5%
2 married 898.989.899 88,456%
3 married  23.939.004      92
4     fff          NA    <NA>


Thank you very much. It works! The only thing is that after that we have to execute df2[df2=='NA']<-NA

It is very slow, due to the fact that I have millions of observations. Is there a faster way?

@newfinder cannot think of anything faster than prettyNum.

The warning message is just highlighting that it is problematic to use a decimal separator in place of a comma and could cause issues in data entry or calculations. You could quiet this warning using options(warn=-1) or set a different separator for the decimal mark to avoid collisions.
The education column is converted to a string because numeric columns only supports numeric data types (e.g., integers or decimals). A value with multiple decimal points does not fit the numeric data type so it is incompatible with numeric representation.
You can convert the NA value from string using dplyr::na_if()
df2<- df1 %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~dplyr::na_if(prettyNum(., big.mark="."),"NA")))
str(df2)
print(is.na(df2))


It is very slow, due to the fact that I have millions of observations. Is there a faster way?

Have a look at this thread for a faster method of replacing the values https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835942/fast-replacing-values-in-dataframe-in-r
